# How can I get the sorted entity list from WCF Data service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am working on WCF, EntityFramework 6 project. I want to get entity metadata. Currently metadata gives entity list unordered from its entity name. As example,

```xml
<EntityType Name="ABCAnalysis">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="ABCClassification" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
<Property Name="ABCDescription" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Translation">
<EntityType Name="Language">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="LanguageName" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
<Property Name="ISO" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="AcademicTitle">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="AcademicTitleName" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
<Property Name="AcademicTitledescriptionMale" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Accountability">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="AccountabilityName" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
<Property Name="AccountabilityDescription" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max"/>
</EntityType>
```

LIke you see my response is not sorted from EntityType name. Its random and I don't know why.

Now I want to make it sorted by its entity name. Because there are some legacy code consume this metadata to create some list. If I can sort this metadata output this will help me to fix lot of problems in my work.

My knowledge on WCF and EF 6 is not so much and I don't know this is due to my bad implementation of either WCF or EF. Or Do I need to do another configuration somewhere.

Any help or comment will be very help full. (At least a way to find a solution).

If the above xml is unclear below I have mention default response of WCF.

```xml
<atom:title>Default</atom:title>
<collection href="ABCAnalysis">
<atom:title>ABCAnalysis</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Translation">
<atom:title>Translation</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Language">
<atom:title>Language</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="AcademicTitle">
<atom:title>AcademicTitle</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Accountability">
<atom:title>Accountability</atom:title>
</collection>
```

And I expect result like this,

```xml
<collection href="ABCAnalysis">
<atom:title>ABCAnalysis</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="AcademicTitle">
<atom:title>AcademicTitle</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Accountability">
<atom:title>Accountability</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Language">
<atom:title>Language</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Translation">
<atom:title>Translation</atom:title>
</collection>
```

Comment: Show the EF code. You just need to add an `OrderBy()` to the query?

Comment: Actually what I want to do is call ```http://localhost:8681/MyProject.svc/$metadata``` and get meta data.